# Checking the contents of a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

I need to know if it's possible to check to see if a value resides inside a list or not. And how it can be done.

Basically, the program needs to allow the user to enter a series of numbers inside a list, until the user specifies that they are finished. Which they would do by entering a sequence of numbers, -123.

Here is the code I have so far, it needs to have a while construct. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
enterNum = input()
userList = []
while enterNum != -123:
    for i in range(enterNum):
        userList.append(float(input()))
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
userList = []
while True:
    enterNum = input()
    if enterNum != -123:
        userList.append(enterNum)
    else:
        break
```

Or:

```
userList = []
while enterNum != -123:
    enterNum = input()
    userList.append(enterNum)
```

But you'll end up with -123 in the list

With error catching, since you can't count on the user, I'd do something like this:

```
userList = []
while True:
    try:
        enteredNum = float(input())
        if enteredNum == -123:
            break
        userList.append(enteredNum)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid number")
```

Comment: You might want to catch the ValueError that will inevitably be raised ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done using the in operator but it would probably be best to not add -123 to the list in the first place.  I would also suggest a few additional improvements.  Most importantly, you should handle [exceptions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions) in the event that something other than a number is entered.

```
userList = list()

while True:
    try:
        enteredNum = float(input())
        if enteredNum == -123:
            break
        userList.append(enteredNum)
    except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid number")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as:

```
if num in your_list:
    #do_something
```

Also, to check if something is not in a list, you can do:

```
if num not in your_list:
    #do_something_else
```